# Explanation to a simple C++ code using two while loops

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am in need of help with this simple program, can't quite wrap my head around it. If someone could please explain the steps it takes to get the output it does. (Found it on a website, not mine)

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

// Loop between 5 and 1
int main()
{
    int outer = 5;
    while (outer >= 1)
    {
        // loop between inner and 1
        int inner = outer;
        while (inner >= 1)
            std::cout << inner-- << ' ';

        // print a newline at the end of each row
        std::cout << '\n';
        --outer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1 
2 1
1
```

Comment: And which part is not clear to you. Did you try to go step by step through the program using a debugger, to figure out how the variables change? There isn't much code so you could do that even with pen and paper.

Comment: the code inside [while loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while) is executed repeatedly as long as the condition (which in your case is `outer >=1` for the outer loop and `inner >= 1` for the inner loop) is true

Comment: i am a bit surprised that no answer mentions it (correction: only one). This is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: The part that is not quite clear is what while loop does what, which one is for switching rows and which one is for subtracting the numbers.

Comment: Debugger will take me through the code and execution step by step?

Comment: Yes with the debugger you can execute the code step by step can what how each variable changes.

Comment: Heck, if you have to you can make the debugger go through the program machine instruction by machine instruction. This can be really slow going and it's rarely necessary, but when you need to do it, it's there.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the second while loop subtracts one from inner and prints it out until inner = 1. Then it goes into the other while loop and subtracts one from outer. It loops through the outer loop until outer = 1. Also it would help to put in breakpoints and run through the program with the debugger to see how the variables change, like @t.niese said.

Comment: So, is it that the first loop is there to say, okay we are in the first row, and then the second loop goes and prints out numbers 5 - 1?

Comment: Ya exactly. Once again i'm going to say you should run through it with the debugger to see how each line affects the variables.

Comment: Ah, that makes it clearer then, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Loop between 5 and 1
// The main function is mandatory in c++ it is called when the program is opened.
int main()
{
    int outer = 5;                      // outer is a count for the outer loop
    while (outer >= 1)                  // while this count is greater than one
    {
        // loop between inner and 1
        int inner = outer;              // initiate a loop in the outer loop
        while (inner >= 1)              // this loop prints the numbers per row
            std::cout << inner-- << ' ';// in every iteration the inner is decreased this creates the 5 4 3 2 1 per line

        // print a newline at the end of each row
        std::cout << '\n';              // Near the end of the outer loop there is a newline
        --outer;                        // Outer is decreased by 1.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the comment that made it a lot easier for me is the one next to the inner while loop, think I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You want to print out 5 lines. `outer` keeps track of how many more lines you have left to print (it starts at 5 and is decremented at the end of the outer while loop.

Then, on each line, you want to print out a decreasing sequence of numbers. This sequence contains 'n' numbers and also starts with n, then goes to n-1, and so on until it reaches 1. Luckily, we have `outer` already defined, which is basically n. So to generate that sequence, you make a variable `inner` which starts at n (or `outer`) and goes down by one (and also gets printed every time in that loop). Once input gets below 1, we stop because we don't want to print 0.

Answer (score 0):

1. Outer while loop runs in order outer = 5,4,3,2,1. `--outer` decrements the value of `outer` in each iteration.
2. The inner loop starts with `inner` set to `outer`. That is, say, in the second iterator, value of `outer` is `4`. Then inner loop goes over the values `4,3,2,1`.
3. One thing to understand here is the post-decrement operator. `std::cout << inner-- << ' ';` this line will first use the value of inner and then decrement it. That is, inner will first be printed and then decremented. For eg. if inner is say `4`, it will first print `4` and then the decrement comes into effect. Thus, for the second iterator, the inner loop will print `4 3 2 1`.

Comment: This explained it really nicely, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In start 
**Outer = 5**
then 
**Inner =5 **
Now inner loop executes 5 times and every time it decrements the **inner**. After inner loop executes 5 time the **outer** decrement statement is executed:

```
--outer;
```

now **outer=4**  and again comes to inner loop so **inner=4** and again the upper procedure is executed.